# .htaccess redirect user upon specified HTTP HOST

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Due to some internal problems and refusal from another part, I need a way to redirect ALL access from a specified domain. So far I've come up with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bad-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/bad-request.html
```

Which doesn't work. Worth noting is that I'm not good with rewrites, but I'm trying to learn. 
I've sucessfully implemented this in PHP, but that requires the code in every project, which really isn't the way to go.

All suggestions, tips and answers are appreciated that puts me in the right direction.

Comment: I have the impression you confuse the requesting and the requested host in your notation, because you write "from a specified domain". Please make clear what you mean: is "bad-domain.com" the domain you are hosting or some external network you want to block ?

Comment: @arkascha Excuse me, I somehow missed your comment. It's an external network, a third-party who's pointing a domain to an internal resource, which I'd like to keep somewhat internal, at least not having a domain pointed to it.

Comment: Ok, getting closer... I read that like this: you host some content and someone else controls a domain name that is resolved to your ip address. Thus browsers asking for an url like http:// somewhere.bad-domaincom/something trigger your server and you want to deny these requests.

Comment: @arkascha Exactly! I've found a way (`strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'bad-domain') !== FALSE)`) to do this in PHP, but that gets really messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason why this should not work. Please check these points again:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bad-domain.com [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/bad-request.html
```

As Alexander Støver pointed out:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Then, if you put those rules in your servers configuration you have to restart the daemon. So probably something like

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Make sure you check the error logfile if the daemon complains about something. Should be something like this:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

or wherever you write your logs to.

If you put those rules into ".htaccess" files (why?) then make sure the server is actually configured to use those files and that you allow to override file paths:

```
AllowOverride:  FileInfo
```

Use logging to debug the rewriting. There are two options for this provided by mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteLog
RewriteLogLevel
```

Comment: Embarasingly enough, I forgot to enable the `RewriteEngine`. However, the ",L" in the `[NC,L]` gives me an internal server error. Thank you for your answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a rule for images.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^187\.10\.226\.42
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```